# How can i use tropo module with node.js?

Tags: node.js, tropo

In my application i need to use tropo application with node.js to send,receive message and call and answer phone calls.I saw the documentation but i didn't get any idea.Can anyone help me.

Comment: A word of caution: The Tropo node.js library and documentation are quite weird, and often wrong. The good news is that Tropo's JSON API is quite straight-forward, and well documented. What I'm trying to say is, stay clear of the node.js library and just send and receive JSON according to the Tropo API docs!

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer - I have never worked with tropo, but this is how I understand it works:

1. You write a script that tropo can parse, in most languages, to perform some function.
2. You link up that script to a number using tropo's web interface.
3. You / a client phones that number, tropo fetches your script and executes it.

Here is a full walkthrough of how everything above works: https://www.tropo.com/docs/scripting/creating_first_application.htm

NOW, if you want your script to do dynamic things, you need to host it yourself. For this you can use node.js:

1. You write a script that changes based on time / user data in node.js
2. You link up the script using tropo's web interface.
3. When someone calls / texts the number, tropo now fetches the dynamic script from your node.js server.

This node.js api can be used to write scripts on your node server: https://github.com/tropo/tropo-webapi-node, https://www.tropo.com/docs/webapi/new_tropo_web_api_overview.htm

Finally, you might want to dynamically create different scripts for different users and hook them up to individual numbers. At this point you use the REST API to automate the "number hooking up work" you used to have to do manually on tropo's website. You can use any node REST client, like [`request`](https://github.com/mikeal/request) to do this. Here are the API docs: https://www.tropo.com/docs/rest/rest_api.htm